# Mapping object without root key to dynamic url?

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm attempting to map the following object:

```
{"walletAccepted":false,"creditCardTypesAccepted":["visa","mastercard","discover","americanexpress"],"paypalAccepted":false}
```

To an object with identical attributes. However, the ResourcePath is dynamic, in that it's along the lines of /paymentmethods/zone/:internalZoneCode

Every attempt I've made at mapping it always ends up with "Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''"

I think the issue is that there is no root key/key path. I've also attempted the following with no luck:

```
RKURL *rkUrl = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[RKClient sharedClient].baseURL resourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/paymentoptions/zone/%@", zoneNumber]];
RKObjectLoader* loader = [[RKObjectLoader alloc] initWithURL:rkUrl mappingProvider:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider];
loader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
loader.delegate = self;

loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[PMZonePaymentMethods class]];
[loader send];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to make it happen is to configure the mapping, and add the mapping to the object manager without a key path or resourcek

So like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* zonePaymentMethodsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PMZonePaymentMethods class]];
[zonePaymentMethodsMapping mapKeyPath:@"walletAccepted" toAttribute:@"walletAvailable"];
[zonePaymentMethodsMapping mapKeyPath:@"creditCardTypesAccepted" toAttribute:@"cards"];
[zonePaymentMethodsMapping mapKeyPath:@"paypalAccepted" toAttribute:@"paypalAvailable"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:zonePaymentMethodsMapping];
```

and use this to make the request:

```
RKURL *rkUrl = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[RKClient sharedClient].baseURL resourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/paymentoptions/zone/%@", zoneNumber]];
RKObjectLoader* loader = [[RKObjectLoader alloc] initWithURL:rkUrl mappingProvider:      [RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider];
loader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
loader.delegate = self;

loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider  objectMappingForClass:[PMZonePaymentMethods class]];
[loader send];
```